# Creating Virtualenv using Anaconda Python Errors

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, anaconda

I'd been working on Python distribution from Anaconda, as default. To use virtual environments, installed virtualenv. It shows that it was installed in the default location as in Anaconda. But, while creating one, it shows error. I do not understand anything as I'm not a pro. Please help. Thanks!!

```
avijit@avijit-Inspiron-3521:~$ virtualenv --version
15.0.3
avijit@avijit-Inspiron-3521:~$ cd Downloads/alieturklmugermany/virtualbcf/
avijit@avijit-Inspiron-3521:~/Downloads/alieturklmugermany/virtualbcf$ virtualenv bcfenv1
New python executable in /home/avijit/Downloads/alieturklmugermany/virtualbcf/bcfenv1/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/avijit/Downloa...f/bcfenv1/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: /home/avijit/Downloads/alieturklmugermany/virtualbcf/bcfenv1/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyCodec_LookupTextEncoding
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/home/avijit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 795, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/avijit/Downloa...f/bcfenv1/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```